Finding involute curve to tangentially join two circles?
I have a bit of a curly maths problem I am struggling to solve.
I am designing a splined connection which must be cut with a tool of 6mm diameter (we'll call that variable m), so there must be outer and inner radius of each tooth of $\frac{m}{2}$. The overall inner and outer diameters (ie circles around the origin which the tool radiuses must be tangent to) must be 76mm and 86mm, we'll call these j and k respectively. There's also 18 teeth which we'll call p. So far so good, and it's easy enough to define the location of these circles as:
$$(x-(\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2}))^2 + y^2 = (\frac{m}{2})^2$$
and
$$(x-(\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2})\cos{(\frac{\pi}{p})})^2 + (y-(\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2})\sin{(\frac{\pi}{p})})^2 = (\frac{m}{2})^2$$
Which gives us something to work with for the outer and inner tooth radiuses for one tooth.
The next step is joining these two circles together with an involute curve, which has the formulas:
$$x = r(\cos(t)+(t-b)\times\sin(t))$$
and
$$y = r(\sin(t)-(t-b)\times\cos(t))$$
Where r is the radius of the base circle, t is the angle in radians and b is the starting angle in radians.
The bit I'm struggling with is to calculate the correct r and b in the involute curve, so that the curve is perfectly tangent to both circles. I'm guessing I need to make a set of simultaneous equations which equate the involute curve to the two circles, however doing this is well beyond my maths capabilities.
Graphically I can get close and this is the kind of thing I am trying to achieve with a general case formula:
graph
Is anyone able to shed some light on how I might tackle this problem?
Thanks!
